# Disable three-finger paste in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, libinput

I am using Libinput gestures to use multi-finger gestures in my ubuntu system. However, whenever I swipe down with three fingers it does two things; both change workspace and paste whatever is on the clipboard to whatever program the cursor had selected.

I have tried following other threads but none have given me a clear answer on how to remove the paste-functionality from the three finger gesture.

Please provide a **simple** guide, as I am no ubuntu pro.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have gnome-tweaks installed (it's a very useful program), you can disable Middle Click Paste in the 'Keyboard & Mouse' tab. I used this to disable it on 19.10, and it should work for you on 18.04.

Gnome Tweaks can be installed from the command line by running `apt install gnome-tweaks` as root. It might alternatively be installable from the Ubuntu Software program.

According to [this github comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49693#issuecomment-390181241), and my own experience, this will not work for Electron apps such as Signal, Discord and Spotify. I don't know whether there is any fully general way to disable it.

Comment: I'd like to do this, as well. When I look at the mouse and keyboard tab in Tweaks, I see "Middle Click Paste" under "Mouse", which is a toggle that has no effect on middle-click behavior, and "Mouse Click Emulation" under "Touchpad" offers three options. Right now, I'm on "Fingers", which bundles up the emulation of 2-for-right, 3-for-middle. The other options don't seem to split this up, but this is irrelevant because switching to "Disabled" does nothing. Weirdly, some of the other options on this tab *do* work. EDIT: It had a delayed disable of 2-finger but *not* 3-finger.

Comment: Sorry @mwchase, I can't quite work out what you're trying to do. Turning off middle-click paste ought to stop pasting on 3-finger click.

Comment: It has no effect. I managed to get things more usable for me by disabling "Tap to Click" in the main settings app. This stops me from accidentally pasting stuff into Discord, at the slight cost of needing to actually try to click in other contexts.

Comment: It seems to be Electron apps like Discord, Signal and Spotify that it doesn't work for - more research required for me I think

Comment: This is still a problem with Ubuntu 20.04. Is there a way to actually honor the setting of "Middle Click Paste"?

Answer (score 0):

1. First install the gnome-tweaks. `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
2. Open tweaks from your application center (to search type tweaks).
3. In the tweaks gui click keyboard & mouse.
4. Under the mouse option disable middle click paste.

(The 3 finger touch is acting like middle click and middle click is assigned to paste what ever you copied last. You just diabled the middle click)